# Tree roots are removing the tiles of my flooring. What to do?

Tags: trees, root-pruning

I have a mango tree in my backyard.

Recently we are seeing that our flooring tiles in room towards my backyard has started protruding because of the roots underneath.

I dont want to cut the tree.
Is there a way for me to save my flooring?

Please let me know.

Comment: Raise your floor.  No, but seriously if the roots are raising your floor you have more to worry about than just tiles.  I assume you have a foundation and walls?  Nothing in a root path will stop it, the roots will always destroy/raise/push aside what is in their path.  Not an arborist, but I would ask a local one as what to do.

Comment: what's under the tiles?

Comment: What kind of house construction and foundation is this? DA&Gunner's answers are assuming a more northern form of construction. When I've seen mangoes growing outside, the typical local housing construction has varied greatly from slab foundation through to something resembling a wood hut...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely going to need to consult with two experts: An arborist and a foundation expert.

If roots have made it under your floor, the foundation is likely compromised to some extent. You'll want someone out there to see how much. If the house was built on a slab, you might be OK and it could be repairable.

As for the tree, the problem is that it's too close to the house. If removing the tree isn't an option, you can maybe somehow cut all the roots on that side, dig a trench and then install some form of root blocker.

Comment: Removing roots compromises tree stability - it can easily fall in opposite direction.

Comment: @sharptooth cutting roots is never ideal, but often viable. It depends on a whole lot of factors.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a concrete slab or other typical foundation.
Mango trees have a deep tap root and typically have dense non-destructive surface feeder roots. They typically would not cause a problem with a concrete slab. The mango tree may not be the problem with your flooring.
Are there any other trees nearby which may be the source of the problem? If so, it may be a good idea to consider removing them.